# How can I write an "if" statement for a string variable in Java?

Tags: java, string

This is what I have so far and I have the problem written as a comment on the line I need help with. Any further suggestions would be welcome too. I just need it to end the program when the user enters "stop" as the employee name. Thanks in advance.

```
package payroll_program_2;
import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
            float hours;                                            
            float rate;                                            
            String name;
            float total_pay;


        System.out.println("Please enter employee name");         
            name = input.next();
                if (stop)               //THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH. I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO WRITE
                    end program             //IT CORRECTLY, SO I JUST TYPED WHAT I NEED IT TO DO.
                {

                }
        System.out.println("Please enter hourly rate");              
            rate = input.nextFloat();                               
            if (rate <0)                                            
                {                                                     
                    System.out.printf("Pay rate cannot be negative");   

                }
        System.out.println("Please enter hours worked");            
            hours = input.nextFloat();                                
             if (hours <0)
                {
                    System.out.printf("Hours cannot be negative");

                }
        System.out.println("Employee's total pay for this week");   
            total_pay = hours*rate;                                   

        System.out.printf("The total pay for %s is $%.2f\n", name, total_pay);        

}
```

Comment: When you give errors like "Hours cannot be negative" you continue on as if thing error didn't occur. Also `%n` is the best way to place a newline at the end in printf. Generally `double` is a better choice than `float` though it might not matter here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (name.equals("stop")) {  
  return;  
}
```

Comment: thank you Sam. Entering that and a few more tweaks and now I'm done. :) Thank you again

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer that helped you out. click on the checkbox you see on the left. this website works on points accumulated by people answering questions well.

Comment: if ("stop".equals(name)) {  
  return;  
}

To Prevent Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Good point.  I don't believe it's possible for Scanner.next() to return null, though - it'll block until it gets input / throw an exception.